# Redis cache data persistence

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

We need to implement a rather big Redis cache cluster (millions of entries).
Since the initialisation of the cache from data is very costly we need
full persistence of the cache on disk.  We wish to avoid using a database.
What are the options available to us ?

Comment: I develop with Spring Boot